# how to use commit_manually decorator in a Django class based view

Tags: django, decorator

is it possible to use the decorator [commit_manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually) in a Django class based view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you use [any other decorator in a class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views).

I personally like decorating the `dispatch` method on the class view:

```
class ManualCommitView(SomeView):

    @method_decorator(commit_manually)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ManualCommitView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

but that's only worth if you plan on reusing the view, otherwise it's easier to just decorate the view in the `URLconf`.